# Remove repeated output

Tags: java, hashmap, output

I'm working on a beginner Java tutorial about Hashmaps and am presented with the below task

```
// Create a method called printOccurrences(int[] scores)
        //
        // HINT: Use a HashMap to keep track of the counts (K: Integer, V: Integer)
        // For int[] scores = {85,93,96,96,92,100,91,85,87,92}
        // Desired Output Is:
        //  85 - 2
        //  87 - 1
        //  92 - 2
        //  93 - 1
        //  96 - 2
        // 100 - 1
        //
```

Below is my code

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Ex5_NumberOfOccurrences {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] scores = {85,93,96,96,92,100,91,85,87,92};
        printOccurrences(scores);
    }
        public static void printOccurrences (int[] scores){
            HashMap <Integer, Integer> tracker = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < scores.length; i++){
                int count = 0;
                for (int j =  0; j< scores.length; j++){
                    if (scores [i] == scores[j]){
                        count ++;
                    }   
                }
            tracker.put(scores[i], count);

            System.out.println( scores[i] + "-" + tracker.get(scores[i]));
            }           
        }
}
```

The code runs, however my output has repeated values as shown below.

```
85-2
93-1
96-2
96-2
92-2
100-1
91-1
85-2
87-1
92-2
```

Does anyone know how may I avoid the repeated output values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You print the tracker output at each iteration, that is causing the repeated output. The `HashMap` has correct values stored.

You can try (outside the `for` loop):

```
for (int key : tracker.keySet())
  System.out.println(key + "-" + tracker.get(key));
```

Also, instead of using multiple `for` loops you can use `tracker` (`HashMap`) to keep track:

```
for (int score : scores) {
  if (tracker.constainsKey(score))
    tracker.put(score, tracker.get(score) + 1);
  else
    tracker.put(score, 1); //Init for each score
```

Comment: `for (int key : tracker.keySet())
  System.out.println(key + "-" + tracker.get(key));` works perfectly! However just to make sure I understand properly, am I correct to say you are creating a Set view of the HashMap I created, and printing output based on the Set view?

Comment: the keys being unique, using `keySet` - Returns a `Set` view of the keys contained in this map, over which we iterate here. So, you are correct, but here we have set view only of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Since your println is inside the outer for loop you're printing the result every time you hit a value in the scores array.

More in the spirit of the question I think, try to rewrite like this:

```
for each score - 
   if the map has the score key - 
     pull the value out of the map and increment it, return it to the map
   else 
     insert into the map (key, 1)
```

The difference is that this will give you linear performance rather than quadratic (i.e this version will run in time proportional to the length of the input array, since you'd only be scanning through the array once, while your version will run in time proportional to the square of the array length).

Comment: is `the map has the score key` return true if it exist? If yes then it should work current code also.

Comment: Yeah but OP ask here why map contains two same key!!. as map will override result of key if same key occurs next time. you should elaborate it, that will help him.

Comment: Follow it through- i.e. 1: outer loop finds 85. Inner loop finds 1 instance, then 2nd. writes (85, 2) to the map. Map prints "85-2". 2: outer loop finds next 85. Inner loop finds 1, 2, writes (85, 2) to the map (which overwrites the previous).

To make this easier to see, format the code properly and then walk through the iterations manually.